# Angular Production Build

Tags: angular

Can I generate production build with both PWA/Service worker and App Shell both ? or this are separate features cannot be placed in one single production build.

or yes i.e. can be generated can anyone please let me know how ?

Asking because when I do "ng build --prod" it generate production build with Service worker but when i run command "ng run my-app:app-shell" it generate build with app shell only.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command, it should work to build with both:

`ng run my-app:app-shell -c production`

Or

`ng run my-app:app-shell:production`

[Official Docs](https://angular.io/guide/app-shell) | Github [issue discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11478)